# Cropping matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

for examples, I have a 6x6 matrix, then I want to take out the small matrix which is located in the center of that matrix, say 2x2. Is there any smart way to do it ? Or I have to loop through the old matrix and then copying values to new one?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this an arbitrary, variable size matrix in the middle? Do you need it to be dynamic?

Comment: I will need it to be dynamic

Comment: I would consult @ascorbes answer, but replace the specifics with variables. Where those variables get their values will depend on how you want to do it.

Comment: thank you Acorbe's answer works well for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can. try for instance

```
A = rand(6,6);  % // big matrix, an example
B = A(3:4,3:4); % // central sub matrix obtained using indices
```

which (in this case) is also equivalent to

```
B = A([3 4],[3 4]);
```

In general you can extract subvectors from a vector selecting the indices you are interested to.